# jquery masked input have only first number optional rest mandatory

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput, jquery-mask

Im using jquery masked input plugin and need to have a phone field with the following format:

```
1 (222) - 000 - 1114
```

my code looks like this:

```
$("#myPhone").mask("9 (999) - 999 - 9999");
```

now i cant seem to get it to work to make the first digit optional but the rest mandatory. So the following numbers are **valid**:

```
1 (222) - 000 - 1114
  (222) - 000 - 1114
```

and the following numbers are **invalid**

```
1 (222) - 000 - 11
  (222) - 00  - 0011
```

using **"?9 (999) - 999- 9999"** will not work since it makes the whole thing optional

If this cant be done in masked can someone help me out with regular expression to achieve this?

Comment: I would first check if there are 11 digits, and after that use a mask in a function.

Comment: @GGio Yeah how do you make sure the first digit is exactly a digit? In my case I want know if it is a +

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$.mask.definitions['~'] = '([0-9] )?';
$("#myPhone").mask("~(999) - 999 - 9999");
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks alot. One problem though the first digit is not strictly digit, if i type letter it types in letter

Comment: This is not a good solution. This fix the problem if you start typing on the input. But if you recovery the data from the database (for example) and apply the mask your input are blank.

Comment: Yeah how do you make sure the first digit is exactly a digit? In my case I want know if it is a +

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect, but you can use number or whitespace:

```
$.mask.definitions['~'] = '[0-9 ]';
$("#myPhone").mask("~(999) - 999 - 9999");
```